# Object ArrayList loses String values after deserialization?

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist

so i have a three class video store GUI and it is supposed to save records of videos in stock. however it saves the video objects using serialization but for some reason ,even though i am not getting any errors, only the numerical values are making it through..

[image]

notice how the leftmost three columns and the rightmost column are all empty. this is because they are meant to have strings in them, and yet they dont...

as i said im not getting any errors so this truly confuses me.

constructor of VideoStore.java(the GUI class):

```
public VideoStore() {
        initComponents();
        model = (DefaultTableModel)displayVideos.getModel();
        try{
        BinaryFile = new BinaryFile();
        BinaryFile.load();
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
            for(int j = 1; j < BinaryFile.videosList.size(); j ++) {
            Video load = (Video)BinaryFile.videosList.get(j);
            String tempName = load.getVideoName();
            String tempProd = load.getProducer();
            String tempRat = load.getRating();
            String tempGenre = load.getGenre();
            short tempNum = load.getVidNum();
            float tempPrice = load.getvideoPrice(); 

            try {
                Object[] row = {ID, tempName, tempProd, tempGenre, tempPrice, tempNum, tempRat};
                model.addRow(row);
            } catch(Exception e){

            }

            ID++;
        }
    }
```

and then the BinaryFile class that i use to handle the .ser file:

```
public void load(){
        try
      {
         FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("/Users/hanaezz/Desktop/output.ser");
         ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
         videosList = (ArrayList)in.readObject();
         in.close();
         fileIn.close();
      } catch(Exception i)
      {
         i.printStackTrace();
         return;
      }
    }

    public static void adderoo(Video v) {
        videosList.add(v);
    }
```

finally, the video class that is in the ArrayList:

```
private static String videoName;
private static String producer;
private static String rating;
private static String genre;
private short videoNumber;
private float videoPrice;
```

Answer (score 6):

Static variabled are **NOT** serialized, you should put:

```
private String videoName;
private String producer;
private String rating;
private String genre;
private short videoNumber;
private float videoPrice;
```

in your video class. 
The only static variable you should put in a Serializable class is `serialVersionUID` (which is used by the serialization and deserialization process). As in:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

Comment: Right answer, but the fact that they were `static` in the first place is just a sign of a much bigger problem.